# git diff-index with path, does it work?

Tags: git, indexing, diff

I'm at the tip of master in my repository.  No local changes.

```
git diff-index HEAD -- "*"
```

correctly returns nothing.

However,

```
git diff-index HEAD -- "*.c"
```

returns me all my C files, as if the repository did not have them at all, like so:

```
:000000 100644 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 c0054a0b0a441090184a141ee73954a94a2904d5 A  block-sha1/sha1.c
:000000 100644 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 c59b0c98fefefc413c8330715fffcc83142d5b2d A  builtin/add.c
:000000 100644 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 fc43eed36b55e4966796490b8c0a02fae790229c A  builtin/annotate.c
:000000 100644 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000 84a8a0b52136c4d1e43ec10f9ef5ed76b7d3c12f A  builtin/apply.c
```

--cached does not help in any way.

Is it a bug or a feature?

Comment: What do you mean `as if the repository did not have them at all.` Why don't you paste the oupout of the second command?

Comment: Let me paste it into the question.